# Data import speeds from Amazon S3 in to Redshift / Redshift solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Does anyone know how fast the copy speed is from Amazon S3 to Redshift?

I only want to use RedShift for about an hour a day, to run updates on Tabelau reports. The queries being run are always on the same database, but I need to run them each night to take in to account new data that's come in that day.

I don't want to keep a cluster going 24x7 just to be used for one hour a day, but the only way that I can see of doing this is to Import the entire database each night into Redshift (I don't think you can't suspend or pause a cluster). I have no idea what the copy speed is so I have no idea if its going to be relatively quick to copy a 10GB file in to Redshift every night.

Assuming its feasible, my thinking is to push the incremental changes on SQL Server dbase in to S3. Using Cloud Formation, I automate the provisioning of a Redshift cluster at 1am for 1 hour, import the dbase from S3, and schedule Tableau to run its queries between that time and get its results. I keep an eye on how long the queries take, and If I need longer than an hour I just amend the cloud formation.

In this way I hope to keep a really 'lean' Tableau server by outsourcing all the ETL to Redshift, and buying only what I consume on Redshift.

Please feel free to critique my solution, or out right blow it out of the water. Otherwise If the consensus of the answer is that importing is relevantly quick, It gives me a thumbs up I'm headed in the right direction with this solution.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Redshift loads from S3 are very quick, however Redshift clusters do not come up / tear down very quickly at all. In the above example most of your time (and money) would be spent waiting for the cluster to come up, existing data to load, refreshed data to unload and cluster to tear down again.

In my opinion it would be better to use another approach for your overnight processing. I would suggest either:

- For a couple of TB, InfiniDB on a largish EC2 instance with the database stored on an EBS volume.
- For many TBs, Amazon EMR with the data stored on S3. If you don't want to get into Hadoop too much you can use Xplenty/Syncsort Ironcluster/etc. to orchestrate the Hadoop element.

Comment: Agree, you can have your data stored to EBS, and take down the DB and EC2 instances for it and bring it up when you need to batch load the new data in and run the reports.  I am an architect for InfiniDB, feel free to message me and I would be glad to help you out with InfiniDB to do this.  We have clusters we take offline and bring up as needed internally for testing and performance runs, so similar use case.  Even if you grow into tens of TBs, that is our space, plenty operate on those loads on or off HDFS.  We are open source GPLv2, so free to try out :)

Comment: @mhoglan I have some InfiniDB questions and came across this post of yours. How can I reach you?

Answer (score 2):

While this question was written three years ago and it wasn't available at that time, a suitable solution to this now would be to use Amazon Athena, which allows on-demand SQL querying of data held in S3.  This works on a pay-per-query model, and is intended for ad-hoc and "quick" workloads like this.

Behind the scenes, Athena uses Presto and Elastic MapReduce, but the only required knowledge for a developer/analyst in practice is SQL.

Tableau also now has a built-in Athena connector (as of 10.3).

More on Athena here: https://aws.amazon.com/athena/

Answer (score 1):

You can presort data you are keeping on S3. It will make Vacuum much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic problem with Redshift... if you looking different way .. Microsoft recently announced new service called [SQL Data Warehouse](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-data-warehouse/) (Uses [PDW](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/analytics-platform-system/) Engine) I think they want to compete directly with Redshift.... Most interesting concept here is ... Familiar SQL Server Query language and Toolset (including Stored proc support). They also decoupled Storage and Compute so you can have 1 GB storage but 10 Compute node for intensive query and vice versa.... they are claiming that compute node start in few seconds and when you resize cluster you don't have to take it offline. Cloud Data Warehouse Battle getting hot :)